# Dynamic htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a dynamic rewrite rule, for URLs that look like this:

```
 /en/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx-_-123.html
 /en/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx-_-3243.html
 /en/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx-_-12.html
```

All of them start with /en/. Then follows a string that can be very different.
They all end with this: -_- and an ID followed by .html.

My try looks like this

```
RewriteRule ^/en/(.*)-_-([0-9]+)\.html$ /en/item/$2 [R=301,L]
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Try without first `/`, `^en/(.*)-_-([0-9]+)\.html$`. Also, try moving the rule to the top of the rewrite file.

Comment: Tried ^en/(.*)-_-([0-9]+)\.html$ without success.

Comment: Here is the full htaccess: https://www.paste.org/99887

Comment: Keep this rule `RewriteRule ^en/(.*)-_-([0-9]+)\.html$ /en/item/$2 [R=301,L]` right after `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: That worked. What line was messing it up? Thanks anyway.